# The netifaces package doesn't work under Python3.4 on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x

I developed my application on Mac OS and it works fine.   On the Mac I get this:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import netifaces
>>> netifaces.version
'0.10.4'
>>> netifaces.interfaces()
['lo0', 'gif0', 'stf0', 'en0', 'en1', 'en2', 'bridge0', 'p2p0', 'awdl0', 'utun1', 'utun0']
```

which is great.  When I move the app to Linux it does not work -- I get this:

```
~$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Jun 17 2015, 22:58:00) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import netifaces
>>> netifaces.version
'0.10.4'    
>>> netifaces.interfaces()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 0] Error
>>>
```

I tried it under **sudo** and got the same thing.

Since I couldn't find a repository with Python3 in it I ended up building the Python3.4 installation from source.   Is it possible that I left something out in the build that netifaces needs?

Other than that does anyone have any idea on how to proceed?

**Update:** My Linux is Ubuntu 12.04 (don't ask I'm stuck there for a while) and the uname -a shows:

```
Linux testsys 3.2.16oa4 #1 SMP Tue Jan 6 16:12:02 PST 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Works fine for me using ubuntu 14.04 using '0.10.4', I also built from source

Comment: What version of linux?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ubuntu 12.04LTS with the 3.2.16 kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please include your Linux information: distribution, version.

Most likely the issue exists because you have built Python 3.4 from source code and Python require distribution specific patches to work correctly on your specific version of Linux. These patches might be omitted from source code distributed on python.org. Consult your distribution issue tracker.

For Ubuntu use deadsnakes repository when installing Python:

https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes